How to Dynamically Populate Schema in WordPress Using XPath Variables?
I have Schema for post type "company" in my WordPress project, but I also have XPath variables but I don't know what to do with them. Can anyone who maybe have worked in XPath help me integrate it with schema?
The XPath Variables:
xpath:movingcompany.name:body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h1[1]
xpath:movingcompany.address:body/main[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[2]/span[1]
xpath:movingcompany.image:body/main[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/img[1]
xpath:movingcompany.aggregateRating.ratingValue:body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]
xpath:movingcompany.aggregateRating.ratingCount:body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[2]
xpath:movingcompany.aggregateRating.reviewCount:body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[2]
xpath:movingcompany.openingHoursSpecification.opens:body/main[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[1]/span[1]
xpath:movingcompany.openingHoursSpecification.closes:body/main[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[1]/span[1]

The Schema:
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "MovingCompany",
  "name": "{{movingcompany.name}}",
  "address": "{{movingcompany.address}}",
  "image": "{{movingcompany.image}}",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "{{movingcompany.aggregateRating.ratingValue}}",
    "ratingCount": "{{movingcompany.aggregateRating.ratingCount}}",
    "reviewCount": "{{movingcompany.aggregateRating.reviewCount}}"
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "opens": "{{movingcompany.openingHoursSpecification.opens}}",
    "closes": "{{movingcompany.openingHoursSpecification.closes}}",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
    ]
  }
}

I tried discovering how to configure XPath Variables and integrate them with Schema, but I couldn't find a valid solution that worked.
Thanks beforehand for a lend of a hand.

XPath is for extracting data from XML/HTML. What;s going to use your templated schema? I think you need to make that processor replace the {{ }} in your schema with the values returned by the corresponding XPaths queries on the page.

It's needed for SEO Rich Results. SEO Specialists asked me to provide this schema for them, that's why

I haven't worked with XPath before. I have the script in my header.php of my WordPress Project, but for example {{movingcompany.aggregateRating.value}} doesn't provide a valid value, says google rich results test. But I also don't what to do or how to configure/setup xpaths.

I guess that {{movingcompany.aggregateRating.ratingValue}} should be replaced with the JSON-escaped result of the XPath expression: //body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]; it isn't hard to code in php but you're using wordpress, not plain php...

I tested your suggestion. But when I do, Google Rich Results test isn't showing any errors but it's showing //body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1] as a value. Is that fine? Will it at the end show the actual rating value? Tho another note to mention, if I pass some characters like asdf, it shows "not valid" error.

I don't think Google will process the XPath expressions itself; you probably have to generate a schema for each of your pages. Where did you get the colon-delimited file (where the XPaths are stored)? They should provide some tips on how to use it no?

SEO Specialists provided me the XPaths. They use some Chrome extension. It says Use the code below in conjunction with the seoClarity platform to easily deploy your schema across your entire site easily. before the XPaths and the Schema Script.

Did you try the plugin? Or do you want to generate each schema with an other tool?

No. I put the schema script customly for each "company" post type posts by checking with the function is_singular("company");. But I'm assuming if I want to use XPaths, I need this plugin, and I see that it's paid.

You'll probably need their plugin if you want to use their templates directly in WP. What you can do is to write an XPath or XQuery snippet that uses these templates to generate a JSON for each page; but you'll have to import the generated JSON in WP afterwards.
